# Logcat filter not working

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm working through a few Android applications and whenever I try to filter out the LogCat to find why my app is not running, nothing shows up anymore.

I've tried going to DDMS, resetting the adb and restarting Eclipse. I've also tried to make sure my Emulator is selected from the list of devices, although my app does not seem to be present under the Emulator (com.android.myapp), so not sure if that's the issue.

I also do realize that this question has been asked many times but I can't seem to find a fix using other solutions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you.

Also let me know if I need to provide any extra info.